# WebRTC Simulcast/Multistream

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I'm trying to simultaneously show multiple streams from a same video cam but in different resolution qualities. I call getUserMedia() two times, but with different resolution constraints (hd and vga). The problem is that once the stream is first created, new stream cannot be created until first one is destroyed/stopped. The second getUserMedia() should use vga settings, but it uses hd settings from the first getUserMedia().

```
function getMedia(HDconstraints){
navigator.getUserMedia(HDconstraints, successCallback, errorCallback);
}

function getMedia2(VGAconstraints){
navigator.getUserMedia(VGAconstraints, successCallback2, errorCallback);
}
```

successCallback2 is using HDconstraints unless I stop the first stream before calling getMedia2().

Comment: This is interesting because `getUserMedia` should be able to share sources...

Comment: Yes. I've also read about getUserMedia() returning audio and video tracks (MediaTrack), but I haven't found any implementations with multiple video tracks. Any ideas on how to approach to implementation?

Comment: does this happen in both Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: I've solved it (as you may see below), but it works only on Chrome. I tried with Firefox and Opera and each one has different problems. Firefox isn't getting local stream and Opera gets it only in hd resolution for both streams. I guess it'll take some time to standardize this. Should I post another question or report a bug? Thanks for your replies.

Comment: I would post bugs in the logical places as getUserMedia should be able to share sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question: It seems that problem was that I was taking standard resolution ratios (e.g. 1920x1080), but camera's ratio was 1:1,35 leading to deformed picture quality when put in fixed dimensions video tag. Just needed to adjust video constraints to a 1:1,35 ratio (e.g. 1620x1200).